# Customizing Windows Right-Click menus with multiple levels

Tags: windows, customization, right-click

I understand the process needed to customize a right click menu going through the regedit etc. However I need to the ability to go multiple levels such as in applications like WinZip. Here's a picture for clarification of what I need

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9658/multiplemenus.jpg](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9658/multiplemenus.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a Shell Extension; there is a guide for writing one in managed code (C#)  [here](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ShellExtensions). It will involve doing a bunch of interop and implementing COM interfaces that the windows shell will consume, namely [IShellExtInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775096(VS.85).aspx) and [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095(VS.85).aspx).

However, one could argue that writing a Shell Extension in managed code is [not advisable](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx); it will force windows explorer to load the CLR, (or any app that uses the standard windows 'Open File' dialog) - native code (C++) would be a better choice for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will take your advice and avoid .NET when writing a shell extension. I found another reference tutorial that is helping quite nicely here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx

Comment: Raymond Chen also had a post about the headaches involved when using .NET for Shell extensions. It really seemed like a topic best avoided.